# Get distinct values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the following:

```
var array = 
    [
        {"name":"a", "category":1}, 
        {"name":"a", "category":2}, 
        {"name":"b", "category": 1}
        {"name":"b", "category": 2}
    ]
```

I have to get an array of all the distinct names, first found:

```
    [
        {"name":"a", "category":1}, 
        {"name":"b", "category": 1}
    ]
```

I tried with `Set` but I still get the full array, what am I doing wrong?

That is my code:

```
{data.length > 0 && [
        ...new Set(
          data.map(item => {
            item.name;
            const pageChanges = {
              departmentId: item.id,
              departmentName: item.name,
            };

            return (
              <Tile
                text={item.name}
                key={item.id}
              />
            );
          }),
        ),
      ]}
```

Comment: which cadegory do you want? only the first found?

Comment: @TylerRoper, Nina Scholz Yes

Comment: @dota2pro, I'm not asking _how_ to do it, I'm asking _what's wrong_ with what I did, this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just filter the duplicates based on the `name` prop

```
let values = array.filter((a, i, self) => {
    return i === self.findIndex(z => z.name === a.name);
});
```

Comment: Please note that the question is *"what am I doing wrong?"*. While this code is a working alternative, it doesn't really attempt to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

With your approach, you insert into the set unique values, not the first item of the same name, but with `id` as well. the result is basically the same as you have before converting.

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter unknown names.

```js
var array = [{ name: "a", "category": 1 }, { name: "a", "category": 2 }, { name: "b", "category": 1 }, { name: "b", "category": 2 }],
    names = new Set,
    distincts = array.filter(({ name }) => !names.has(name) && names.add(name));
    
console.log(distincts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, using the Array.map function, each element in the array gets edited in place. This means that the resulting array.length will always be the same as the original array.length. Something you can do is to do a map and then filter, but then might as well do a filter or reduce in the first place. Putting them in a set is a good idea, but objects aren't equal `{}!={}` so they will all be inserted.